# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at ../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using vagrant with virtualbox. I get this error when inserting data to database. Things I have tried to fix the error:

- Clear all caches, routes and config
- Made sure my env file is configured (I already tried to replace the 127.0.0.1 to localhost)
- Verify if the login info is correct (I even made a new user and I get the same error, If i enter wrong pass or user it does throw the correct error)
- **On the side of the two I mentioned Migrations do work!**
- I inserted data on the xampp phpmyadmin to the table and it also works
- My laravel version is 6.4.1 and I downloaded homestead from the repo and used the command laravel new laravel "name of application" to create the proyect

I am having this problem (I dont know what else to do) that everytime I attempt to insert data with laravel using homestead i get this error on the logs:

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for 

user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(46): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)
#2 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(182): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#5 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(920): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#6 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(453): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
#7 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(658): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('insert into pos...', Array)
#8 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(625): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into pos...', Array, Object(Closure))
#9 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(460): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('insert into pos...', Array, Object(Closure))
#10 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(412): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->statement('insert into pos...', Array)
#11 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(349): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->insert('insert into pos...', Array)
#12 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(239): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->__call('insert', Array)
#13 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/routes/web.php(42): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('insert', Array)
#14 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar->{closure}()
#15 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(179): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runCallable()
#16 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(680): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#17 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#32 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#34 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#49 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 /home/vagrant/code/first-app/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 {main}
"}
```

My .env file has the following configuration:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:zkV082cDVD5ScGfF26O2RpY8RFYZvmuyd8Qo7jBJCuY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost (or 127.0.0.1)
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

My code is the following on web.php:

```
Route::get('/insert', function (){
   DB::insert('insert into posts(title, content) values(?,?)', ['Php','Laravel']);
});
```

I made a migration with the code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->tinyInteger('is_admin')->default('0');
    });
}
```

Comment: This is an SQL error not a laravel error

Comment: Check the permissions on the SQL table (SQL Users) also configure your laravel .env file correctly

Comment: @BobbyAxe yeah it is correct, I used the command that pr1nce mentioned below and now I get this error "C:\laravel-apps\first-app\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Protocol error

Comment: are you using a virtual machine for your site ?

Comment: @N69S Yes, I am using vagrant with virtualbox... i forgot to mention that. I will update my post.

Comment: well, your vagrant installation can't access your xamp database.

Comment: calm down, In your index.php in laravel app check the connection first in core php and let me know?

Comment: first try tinker then check error

Comment: sometimes issues with cache, so you can directly replace the connection values in database.php also do run these two commands.

Run `php arttisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, your vagrant installation can't access your xamp database.

When you launch migration via the CMD in your windows, it uses the database on your machine (xamp)

But when you access it through the web server on your vagrant virtual machine, it will uses that machine's database. wich by default has user "root" and password "root" or "123".

Either case, you should update your `.env` with the right credentials and migrate from the CLI of your virtual machine (`vagrant ssh`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the code but in your env file.

Setup your env file with the right credentials and then run `php artisan config:cache` command so laravel will load your credentials.

In your question you mentioned you cleared cache. That's not enough you need to use `config:cache`

Update:

Run `php artisan optimize:clear` based on your new issue with the storage folder.

Comment: Have been lookin for something like this it worked but... now I get this error "There is no existing directory at "C:\laravel-apps\first-app\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Protocol error

Comment: Updated my answer try  it

Comment: I am doing all this locally. I tried to google but most answers mention this on FTP servers or changing permissions on linux.

Comment: Did you run the new command i post in my answer? I updated my answer before a few minutes based on your new error

Comment: @pr1nce I tried it this moment and it went back to the last error I had :(.

Comment: Just in case I am using vagrant with virtualbox for my site.

Comment: And you run all the artisan commands from inside vagrant right? Using vagrant ssh and you are on your vagrant project